# $u$ is an algebraic integer. Monic polynomial with conjugate of $u$ its zeros have integer cofficients.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have a proof of the following question. I want to know if it is correct, and if there is a shorter proof.

> Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a finite extension with $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=n$.
> $O_k$ is the ring of algebraic integers in $K$. $u\in O_K$.
> $\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n$ are the $n$ $\mathbb{Q}$-monoomorphisms of $K\to\mathbb{C}$.
> Prove that $g(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-\sigma_i(u))\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

My proof: **claim**: $g$ is the field polynomial of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.
(i.e. Let $\psi:K\to K$, $x\to ux$ be the linear transformation on $K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $g$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\psi$.)

Let $u_1(=u),\cdots,u_m$ be the $m$ distinct roots of $irr(u,\mathbb{Q})$. Then consider the field extension $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(u)\subseteq K$. Every $\mathbb{Q}$-monoomorphism $\mathbb{Q}(u)\to\mathbb{C}$ has $\frac{m}{n}$ ways to be extended to $\mathbb{Q}$-monoomorphism $K\to\mathbb{C}$, and there are $m$ $\mathbb{Q}$-monoomorphism $\mathbb{Q}(u)\to\mathbb{C}$, respectively maps $u$ to $u_1(=u),\cdots,u_m$. Hence $g(x)=(\prod_{i=1}^m (x-u_i))^{\frac{m}{n}}=(irr(u,\mathbb{Q}))^{\frac{m}{n}}$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\psi$. ( That $(irr(u,\mathbb{Q}))^{\frac{m}{n}}$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\psi$ is a well-known fact. A proof can be found in Zariski's Commutative Algebra, Volume $1$, Theorem $20$ of Chapter $2$.) **This is our claim.**

Now we return to proving $g\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It is well known that exists a basis $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ of  $K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, s.t. $O_k=\oplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}x_i$. Under that basis, $ux_i\in O_k$ and hence is a linear combination of $x_1,\cdots, x_k$ with integer entries, namely
the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ as defined above shall have integer entries. Hence $g(x)=\det(xI_n-A)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. $\square$

---

---

**My original proof, which is wrong as is pointed by user Sam Ballas, since $\sigma_i$ may not fix $x_j$:**

**claim**: $g$ is the field polynomial of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.
(i.e. Let $\psi:K\to K$, $x\to ux$ be the linear transformation on $K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $g$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\psi$.)

proof: Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ be a basis of  $K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. $A=(a_{ij})\in\mathbb{Q}_{n\times n}$ be the matrix of $\psi$ under the basis:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
ux_1 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
ux_n
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ 
\cdots &  & \cdots \\ 
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
x_n
\end{pmatrix}.  $$

Apply $\sigma_k$ to both sides and note that $\sigma_k(a_{ij})=a_{ij}$, $\sigma_k(x_i)=x_i$ since $\sigma_k$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-monoomorphism, we yield

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_i(u)x_1 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
\sigma_i(u)x_n
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ 
\cdots &  & \cdots \\ 
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ 
\cdots \\ 
x_n
\end{pmatrix}.  $$

This implies $\det(\sigma_i(u)I_n-A)=0$ and hence $\sigma_i(u)$ is a zero of $f(x)=\det(xI_n-A)$. Since $\sigma_i(u)$ are all distinct since $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is separable, and $f(x)=\det(xI_n-A)$ have degree $n$, and
$g(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-\sigma_i(u))\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $f(x)=\det(xI_n-A)$ are both monic, we infer $f(x)=g(x)$, **which is our claim**. (I also wonder if this claim itself is true.)

Now we return to proving $g\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It is well known that exists a basis $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ of  $K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, s.t. $O_k=\oplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}x_i$. Under that basis, $ux_i\in O_k$ and hence is a linear combination of $x_1,\cdots, x_k$ with integer cofficients, namely
the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ as defined above shall have integer entries. Hence $g(x)=\det(xI_n-A)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. $\square$

Comment: What is your definition of an algebraic integer?

Comment: @Servaes He does give the definition, it's the ring of algebraic integers of $K$. An algebraic integer is a root of a monic integral polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect because you use the faulty assumption that $\sigma_k(x_i)=x_i$. There is no reason to believe that if you pick an aribitrary basis for $K$ that this will be true. In fact, if you are thinking of $K$ as an abstract field (not embedded in $\mathbb{C}$) then expression doesn't make sense since $\sigma_i(x_k)$ and $x_k$ live in different spaces.

There is definitely a shorter proof that uses some Galois theory and a bit of algebraic number theory. Let $E$ be the Galois closure of $K$ (embedded in $\mathbb{C}$) and let $G=Gal_{\mathbb{Q}}(E)$ be its Galois group. It is not so hard to show using the primitive element theorem that for each $\tau\in G$ there is a permutation $\alpha$ of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ such that $\tau\circ \sigma_i=\sigma_{\alpha(i)}$. In other words, the Galois group permutes the embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$.

Next, observe that the coefficients of the polynomial you are interested in are all symmetric polynomials in the $\sigma_i(u)$'s. For instance the constant term is (up to sign) $\sigma_1(u)\ldots\sigma_n(u)$. Since the coefficients are symmetric and the Galois group permutes the $\sigma_i$'s it follows that any symmetric expression in the $\sigma_i(u)$'s is in the fixed field of the Galois group. By elementary Galois theory, this is $\mathbb{Q}$.

For the other point. Suppose that $u\in O_K$. Then we have that for each $i$, $\sigma_i(u)$ is an algebraic integer (in $E$). The algebraic integers in $E$ form a ring and so any polynomial expression in the $\sigma_i(u)$'s is an algebraic integer. However, by the above argument, symmetric expressions in the $\sigma_i(u)'$ are rational. However, it is a standard result that the rational algebraic integers are precisely the normal integers (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$). Thus the for an algebraic integer, the coefficients all lie in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks! I did not imagine I have made such a silly (I have to say) mistake.

Comment: However I think my proof can be mended: So we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 \sigma_i(u)\sigma_i(x_1) \\ 
 \cdots \\ 
 \sigma_i(u)\sigma_i(x_n)
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ 
 \cdots &  & \cdots \\ 
 a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_i (x_1 )\\ 
 \cdots \\ 
\sigma_i( x_n)
\end{pmatrix}.$$ (to be continued $\cdots$)

Comment: ($\cdots$) And since $\{\sigma_i(x_j)\}_{1\le j\le n}$ is a basis of $\sigma_i(K)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, we still have $\sigma_i(u)$ is a zero for $f(x)=\det(xI_n-A)$. Hence the claim "$g$ is the field polynomial of $K/\mathbb{Q}$" is still true, and the proof goes on. Is my proof now correct?

Comment: So the basic idea behind your proof is that the $\sigma_i(u)$ are eigenvalues of some linear map, but you need to think carefully about what the domain of the map is. One way to do this is to think of the matrix you write as defining a linear map on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then you can probably use the argument you mention to show that the $\sigma_i(u)$ are eigenvalues of this linear map

Comment: Thanks. Here I view $K$ as subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ exactly. (Sorry for my temporarily removing the acceptance, because I want more comments on my new argument,)

Comment: For what its worth, I think your updated proof is correct

Comment: @Asigan, perhaps if you don't get more comments soon you could re-accept my answer.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: (I have to say this is still wrong, since $\sigma_i(u)$ need not be all distinct, one immediate example is $u=1$. I have edited a new proof and this time it seems correct. This comment intends to remind others who also read this. I do not want to delete my previous comment, for if others make the same mistake, they may realize when they see this. :) )